# How do I redirect with a Drop Down List, and not a Button?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am looking into using only a ddl to run my query, not a ddl and a Button_Click function.  I am yet to find what to do.  How do I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect? or are you trying to run a query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your as(p/c)x:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
                  id="ddl"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectionChanged"
                  AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Page 1" Value="/page1.aspx" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Page 2" Value="/page2.aspx" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The "AutoPostBack" property tells ASP.NET to wire up a client-side (javascript) command that submits the form as soon as the drop down list changes, instead of waiting for a button click.

And in your codebehind, the event handler we referenced in the "OnSelectedIndexChanged" property will get fired:

```
protected void SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the AutoPostBack property to true, then hook into the OnSelectedIndexChanged event

```
<asp:DropDownList 
         id="dropDownList1" 
         runat="server" 
         AutoPostBack="true" 
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Server Side

```
void dropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged
                   (Object sender, EventArgs e) {

   //run your query

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your Drop down list has it's "AutoPostback" property set to true.  This will cause the page to post back when the user selects an item from within the drop-down list.  You can respond to this in your code-behind in whichever event you desire, Page_Load, or the DDL's own OnSelectedIndexChanged