# How can I get my Drop Down List to Navigate to Another Page on Item Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Drop Down List control, which I would like for it to send a user to another page in my site once they select one of the options inside it. I am new to Asp.Net/C# and having a hard time figuring out where to place my OnInit() in the code behind, so I can do a redirect to some other page. Can anyone help me with this? Here is my code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

I would like to do this "without" using javascript or JQuery, if possible. If someone could illustrate this out for me, I would be very thankful. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529866/how-do-i-redirect-with-a-drop-down-list-and-not-a-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place this code after setting the

> autopostback

property of Dropdownlist to true

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Home");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Login");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Signup");
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sUrl = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + ".aspx";
        Response.Redirect(sUrl);
    }
```

Comment: Much thanks. In my particular case, I see I must rename the pages I intend to send the user to, but this has allowed me to see the concept of what I need to be doing alot more clear, with addition to response above. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to word of ASP.Net. Look for Response.Redirect method.

```
Response.Redirect(URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //Redirect to other page  
       Response.Redirect("YOUR_NEW_PAGE.aspx");

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the great illustration, gentlemen. :)